# Python FTP Server - Errno 98 Address already in use

Tags: python, sockets, ftp, webserver, websocket

I am running a Python FTP Server on Port 21. The server has been working for weeks now with no problem. I was making some changes to my server code, particularly on the "on_disconnect" method, one of which caused a basic undefined variable error which I quickly fixed. I went back to restart and I got this apparently infamous Errno 98 - Address Already in use Error

At first I thought I would just let the connection time out, so I waited 5 min and tried again, no luck.

I closed all client side connections I could think of, and tried again.

Next, I restarted my terminal, and again no luck

Then I turned to stack overflow, and saw several suggestions to use "kill -9 ....." in various forms, which did not work, but I could have been doing those wrong, as I really don't understand whats going on and none seemed specific to FTP.

I then found the command netstats - which listed I think all the ports I have open? Either way, I couldn't find anything that looked like my ftp server

Lastly, I went to my task manager to see if something was somehow still running in the background, of course nothing was.

At this point, I am at a loss for how to reset my address, it seems like it definitely shouldn't be this hard!

Comment: "task manager"? Sounds like Windows. If so, I suggest applying Universal Microsoft Cure #1: `REBOOT`.

Comment: It's not Windows, its linux (specifically Raspberry Pi)- and yes there is something called Task Manager (which I learned today) and I tried rebooting as well